# Creating and killing threads in Android

Tags: android

I have an application that creates a thread to do some work. When the work is done I kill the thread. Problem is that every time I do kill the thread, the heap seems to have increased by 10k? To test further I did the following in a 1ms handler.

```
TestThread new_thread = new TestThread();
new_thread = null;
```

Every time I run this I see the heap increase under DDMS. The TestThread does nothing. It has no code. Its just an empty thread.

```
import android.util.Log;

public class TestThread extends Thread {

    public TestThread () {
    Log.d("TESTTHREAD","Constructed");
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.d("TESTHREAD","Run");
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

The myThread.stop() method is deprecated because it might leave the application in an 
unpredictable state. Instead, use the following when needed, such as in the onStop() 
method of the parent component:

```
//use to stop the thread myThread 
if(myThread != null) { 
    Thread dummy = myThread; 
   myThread = null; 
    dummy.interrupt(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I do not even start the thread. I don't stop it. I just create a new instance of it. Then set that instance to null. I thought that would have meant Android cleaned up the unused instance of the thread?

Comment: Is it really a bad thing to create new instances of a thread that only last a short time and then are removed? I was looking to do this a lot in my software. I am wondering now if that is just a bad practice. That the memory is always allocated until the activity itself is destroyed even though the thread is shown to be removed when I monitor things in the DDMS.